# roller 1 and roller 2 rpm calculation when diameter is not same

Tags: mechanical-engineering

Can anyone help me with these 3 questions for gear ratio ?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Engineering SE! If you are a new user, please visit the [tour] page. Please consider the following improvements to your question. 1) Type the text in. Text in an image is not easily searchable / readable. 2) Then crop the image to include only the diagram. 3) This sounds like a homework question. Please include the attempts that you have made to solve it. Use the [edit] option below the question to modify it.

Comment: Ratio the diameters.